# Generic Delegate C#

Tags: c#, generics, delegates

Im trying to figure out how to make a generic delegate returning a generic value. 
My first non-generic scenario looks like this.

```
    delegate int FirstDelegate(int i);
    static FirstDelegate method;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        method = ReturnInt;
        int i = method(3);
    }

    static int ReturnInt(int i)
    {
        return i;
    }
```

No problems here. Everything works fine. However when I make it generic things spin out of control.

```
    delegate T FirstDelegate<T>(T i);
    static FirstDelegate<T> method; <--
```

Already here he starts complaining about type or namespace etc etc not found. 
Anyone have any ideas of how to get this working?

Edit: My real goal is that I have a cache that can contain many different cache objects. And now I want a single method that is generic so I can get all objects through this one. I could make it return object or a baseclass, but then I still would have to cast each object everywhere its used.

Dog / cat example 
The non-generic parts are working.. the generic.. not so much

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Clientside
        Cache.method = GetAnimalOnClient;

        //not working
        Cache.methodGeneric = GetAnimalOnClientGeneric;

        var cat = Cache.GetCachedObj(AnimalType.Cat);
        var dog = Cache.GetCachedObj(AnimalType.Dog);

        //Want do
        vad dog = Cache.GetCachedObj<Dog>();
    }

    private static Animal GetAnimalOnClient(AnimalType type)
    {
        if (type == AnimalType.Dog)
            return Cache._Dogs.First();
        else
            return Cache._Cats.First();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This is the one I want to use
    /// </summary>
    private static T GetAnimalOnClientGeneric<T>() where T: Animal
    {
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(Cat))
            return Cache._Cats.First() as T;
        return Cache._Dogs.First() as T;
    }
}

public enum AnimalType
{
    Dog,
    Cat
}

public static class Cache
{
    delegate Animal GetCacheObjectDelegate(AnimalType type);
    public static GetCacheObjectDelegate method;

    delegate Animal GetCacheObjectDelegate<T>() where T : Animal;
    public static GetCacheObjectDelegate<T> methodGeneric; //<--Complains here

    public static List<Dog> _Dogs = new List<Dog>();
    public static List<Cat> _Cats = new List<Cat>();

    public static Animal GetCachedObj(AnimalType type)
    {
        return method(type);
    }

    public static T GetCachedObj<T>() where T: Animal
    {
        return methodGeneric<T>(); //NOPE
    }
}

public class Animal
{

}

public class Dog : Animal
{

}

public class Cat : Animal
{

}
```

Comment: I suspect that was a typo, but what you have there is a field, not a method.

Comment: Ye it's a field that is containing a pointer to the method. I usually name my fields after what they are containing. : )

Comment: That changes things.. I'll revise my answer in a couple of minutes.

Comment: "And now I want a single method that is generic" Which is it? The title says you want a generic delegate, the code shows a generic field, but the update says a generic method...

Comment: Also, please add an actual example of what you're trying to achieve, with actual method/field/class names. Even if it's peuso-code. You say this is about caching, but I don't see why you'd need a field with a type of a generic delegate.

Comment: Ye Im trying to add more code showing exactly what I want.

Comment: There we go. Tried to add an explaination of what Im doing. But it feels like the more I try to explain the blurrier stuffs get.

Comment: Let me get this straight. The "GetObject" behaviour will depend on the type of the object being cached, right? So if I want to retrieve a cached `Dog`, something will happen, if I want a `Cat`, something else will happen, right?

Comment: No I just have both dog and cat in same cache and I dont want to cast it where Im using it. Posting code example in 30 sec.

Comment: I pasted a working example on the dog / cat
now I want to replace
var dog = (Dog)Cache.GetCachedObj(AnimalType.Dog); with
var dog = Cache.GetCachedObj<Dog>(); and still having it working. So I dont need to cast the dog

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're overcomplicating things.

```
public static class Cache
{
    private static List<Dog> _dogs = new List<Dog>();
    private static List<Cat> _cats = new List<Cat>();

    public static TAnimal GetCachedObj<TAnimal>() where T: Animal
    {
        if(TAnimal == typeof(Dog))
           return (TAnimal) _dogs.First();
        else if (TAnimal == typeof(Cat))
           return (TAnimal) _cats.First();
        else throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid generic type argument");
    }
}
```

But your whole design has a flaw: it breaks the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

The LSP states that if `T` (for example, `Cat`) is a subtype of `Animal`, then *any* instance of `Animal` can be replaced with `T` without any surprising effects.

Let me ellaborate. Say that you decide to create a new animal, a `Giraffe`. Now, if you call `GetCachedObj<Giraffe>`, you'll get an exception! The code does *not* work for *any* subtype of `Animal`, the LSP does not hold!

Instead you should make the cache class generic, and use a cache instance for every kind of animal

```
public class Cache<T> where T: Animal
{
    private static List<T> _animals = new List<T>();

    public T GetCachedObj()
    {
        return _animals.First();
    }
}

var dogsCache = new Cache<Dog>();
Dog dog = dogsCache.GetCachedObj();

var catsCache = new Cache<Cat>();
Cat cat = catsCache.GetCachedObj();
```

This will always work for any kind of animal.

Note: I believe `Cache` shouldn't be static. Instead, you can use the Singleton pattern to have one single cache instance across the application (per animal type), or use Dependency Injection (with a framework such as Castle Windsor) to inject a cache into every client.

---

### old answer

You either bind the method's generic type argument to a specific type at *declaration-time* (as @Sean mentioned), or you make the enclosing type generic as well.

```
public class MyClass<T>
{
    public FirstDelegate<T> Method(){...}
}
```

You can also leave `T` unbound (without making the enclosing type generic), but you'll have to declare `T` *after* the method name, like so:

```
public FirstDelegate<T> Method<T>(){...}
```

Either way, at some point in time, `T` will be bound to a specific type. In this case, `T` will be bound when you create an instance of `MyClass` (i.e., `new MyClass<int>`), like you would do with a `List<T>`.

Comment: Then I have to make one handler for every type I want to return. Also I need to call the right handler for right returntype.

Comment: @Evelie I've updated my answer. Lemme know if I missed any requirement.

Comment: @Evelie Updated my answer again.

Comment: even if I make 30 different caches with all my animals I only want one method to get the desired animal. Which in turn has to be generic if I dont want to cast. And my problem is that I cant store such a method no matter what I try. But thanks for your imput. I'm fairly certain now that it's not possible. I will mark you'r answer as the correct one.

Comment: @Evelie I don't see the issue.. the approach I suggested only has one generic method, and there's no casting involved.

Comment: well you are using multiple caches. So I still need to choose the right cache for each object that Im looking for.

Comment: Well yeah, you create an instance for each type of object that needs to be cached. Many caching approaches work like this. I advise this, but of course, the decision is yours :) I hope to at least have helped a bit

Comment: The real solution I use is not so faar from what you ar saying. I have multiple "Caches" like you say but in one "cachecontainer". And this cachecontainer is where im trying to place this generic method, which in turn decides what cache to work with depending on input params. I just tried to simplify things a bit . Unfortunately it doesnt seem possible to make a delegatethingie that is generic :(.  Thanks a lot for your time!

Answer (score 4):

You need to specify the type when declaring `method` :

```
static FirstDelegate<int> method;
```

Comment: Then you declare a `FirstDelegate<string> someMethod`

Comment: In my specific scenario I got 30~ different returntypes making this approach kinda messy. But here is some points : D

Comment: You are always going to have to mention a type at some point so that the compiler will know which method you wish to call.

Comment: I was hoping I could do something like  
delegate T FirstDelegate<T>(T i) where T : MyBaseClass and have all my objects inheriting from the baseclass. Basicly what Im tring to avoid is having to cast the objects fetched from the method everywhere. Seems like it's not possible tho..

Answer (score 0):

If You have an instance of the object You want to get default value, You can use this:

```
public static T GetDefault<T>(T par)
    {
        return default(T);
    }
```

For example:

```
System.Drawing.Point p = new Point();
System.Drawing.Point defaultPoint = GetDefault(p);
```

Answer (score 0):

> My real goal is that I have a cache that can contain many different
>   cache objects. And now I want a single method that is generic so I can
>   get all objects through this one. I could make it return object or a
>   baseclass, but then I still would have to cast each object everywhere
>   its used.

There is no need to use delegates in this particular problem, because LINQ allows selecting objects by type from `IEnumerable`:

```
public class AnimalCache

    private readonly Animals as new HashSet(of Animal)

    public function Add(Animal as Animal) as AnimalCache
        Animals.Add(Animal)
        return me
    end function

    public function GetAnimals(of AnimalType as Animal) as IEnumerable(of AnimalType)
        return Animals.OfType(of AnimalType)
    end function
end class
```

Usage:

```
dim Cache = new AnimalCache().
    Add(new Cat).Add(new Dog).Add(new Cat)

dim CachedCats = Cache.GetAnimals(of Cat)
dim CachedDogs = Cache.GetAnimals(of Dog)
```

Note that if a `Giraffe` class is added into the class hierarchy, `AnimalCache` will still work:

```
public class Giraffe 
    inherits Animal

end class

dim Cache = new AnimalCache().
    Add(new Cat).Add(new Dog).Add(new Giraffe)

dim CachedGiraffes = Cache.GetAnimals(of Giraffe)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a Dictionary in the Cache class, use the Animal class type as the key and List<Animal> as the value.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Cache.AddCacheObj<Dog>(new Dog());
        Cache.AddCacheObj<Cat>(new Cat());

        var cat = Cache.GetCachedObj<Dog>();
        Console.WriteLine("Cat: {0}", cat);

        var dog = Cache.GetCachedObj<Cat>();
        Console.WriteLine("Dog: {0}", dog);     
    }
}

public static class Cache
{
    static Dictionary<Type, List<Animal>> dict = new Dictionary<Type, List<Animal>>();

    public static T GetCachedObj<T>() where T: Animal
    {
        List<Animal> list;
        if (dict.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out list))
        {
            return list.FirstOrDefault() as T;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static void AddCacheObj<T>(T obj) where T: Animal
    {
        List<Animal> list;
        if (!dict.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out list))
        {
            list = new List<Animal>();
            dict[typeof(T)] = list;
        }
        list.Add(obj);
    }
}

public class Animal
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "This is a " + this.GetType().ToString();
    }
}

public class Dog : Animal
{

}

public class Cat : Animal
{

}
```

The output:

```
Cat: This is a Dog
Dog: This is a Cat
```

You can check out the demo code here:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/FYkCw7